# A use case for importing with blank identifier in golang

Tags: go

The Go programming language specification states: "To import a package solely for its side-effects (initialization), use the blank identifier as explicit package name."

For example:

```
import _ "foo/bar"
```

I am having difficulty imagining a use case for this construct. The accepted answer for [Usage of the `import` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24425002/usage-of-the-import-statement/24425363#24425363) mentions a use case where a database driver may be loaded without the need for the importing program to use any of the exported functions of that package, but it leaves out the details to reader's imagination.

Are there real life examples (with code snippets and explanation) that illustrate this use case?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I was writing a program that resizes images. I wanted it to be able to recognize images in different formats like *JPEG*, *PNG*, *GIF* and convert them to *JPEG*.

So in addition to the [`image`](http://golang.org/pkg/image/) and [`image/jpeg`](http://golang.org/pkg/image/jpeg/) packages, I also had to import [`image/png`](http://golang.org/pkg/image/png/) and [`image/gif`](http://golang.org/pkg/image/gif/) only to register their respective decoders.

Had I not imported those, the scaler would *only* be able to read *JPEG* images.

```
package main

import(
  "image"
  "image/jpeg" // I wanted to export the images as JPEG
  _ "image/png"
  _ "image/gif"
)

// ...
```

The relevant documentation from the [`image`](http://golang.org/pkg/image/) package:

> Decoding any particular image format requires the prior registration of a decoder function. Registration is typically automatic as a side effect of initializing that format's package so that, to decode a PNG image, it suffices to have:
>
> ```
> import _ "image/png"
> ```

Answer (score 26):

This is because of the **[init function](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#init)**

> each source file can define its own niladic `init` function to set up whatever state is required. (Actually each file can have multiple `init` functions.)
>
> And finally means finally: `init` is called after all the variable declarations in the package have evaluated their initializers, and those are evaluated only after all the imported packages have been initialized.

That is how the [go-sqlite3](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/blob/ab91e934/sqlite3.go#L234-L236) mentioned in "[What does an underscore in front of an import statement mean in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21225073/6309)" works.

```
func init() {
    sql.Register("sqlite3", &SQLiteDriver{})
}
```

You have another example in "[Understanding Golang Packagese](https://thenewstack.io/understanding-golang-packages)":

> In some contexts, we may need to import a package only for invoking it’s `init` method, where we don’t need to call forth other methods of the package.
> **If we imported a package and are not using the package identifier in the program, Go compiler will show an error**.
> In such a situation, we can use a blank identifier ( `_` ) as the package alias name, so the compiler ignores the error of not using the package identifier, but will still invoke the `init` function.

Answer (score 4):

A use case is when what you want is only the [`init` function](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization) doing some initialization (for example registering themselves so that you don't have to explictely call them).

An exemple is the registring of [some database drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353679/whats-the-recommended-way-to-connect-to-mysql-from-go) :

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/ziutek/mymysql/godrv"
)
```